# R markdown pie chart with for-loop

Tags: r, for-loop, pie-chart, plotly, data-manipulation

I have a question about drawing *pie chart* with **for-loop**.
Here is my raw data.

```
type,com,year,month,value
A,CH,2015,1,0
A,CH,2015,2,0
A,CH,2015,3,0
A,CH,2015,4,0
A,CH,2015,5,0
A,CH,2015,6,0
A,CH,2015,7,0
A,CH,2015,8,2200
A,CH,2015,9,111384
A,CH,2015,10,28758
A,CH,2015,11,21161
A,CH,2015,12,0
A,CH,2016,1,0
A,CH,2016,2,0
A,CH,2016,3,0
A,CH,2016,4,0
A,CH,2016,5,0
A,CH,2016,6,0
A,CH,2016,7,0
A,CH,2016,8,0
A,CH,2016,9,453128
A,CH,2016,10,868256
A,CH,2016,11,1015080
A,CH,2016,12,650912
A,ZU,2015,1,0
A,ZU,2015,2,0
A,ZU,2015,3,0
A,ZU,2015,4,0
A,ZU,2015,5,0
A,ZU,2015,6,61273
A,ZU,2015,7,27711
A,ZU,2015,8,161780
A,ZU,2015,9,48889
A,ZU,2015,10,72805
A,ZU,2015,11,131466
A,ZU,2015,12,73756
A,ZU,2016,1,400
A,ZU,2016,2,0
A,ZU,2016,3,0
A,ZU,2016,4,0
A,ZU,2016,5,0
A,ZU,2016,6,0
A,ZU,2016,7,0
A,ZU,2016,8,10000
A,ZU,2016,9,147533
A,ZU,2016,10,64572
A,ZU,2016,11,57542
A,ZU,2016,12,0
B,CH,2015,1,100
B,CH,2015,2,0
B,CH,2015,3,0
B,CH,2015,4,0
B,CH,2015,5,0
B,CH,2015,6,0
B,CH,2015,7,0
B,CH,2015,8,4025
B,CH,2015,9,2054
B,CH,2015,10,7235
B,CH,2015,11,6421
B,CH,2015,12,3560
```

I use package `plotly` to draw and following is my `.Rmd` code.

````
---
title: "R markdown Pie Chart For-Loop" 
output: 
  html_document:
    css: custom.css
    theme: journal
    toc: true
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
    toc_depth: 4
--- 
```{r setup, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(lubridate)
library(plotly)
```
```{r create-datasets, echo=FALSE}
pie <- read.csv("pie.csv" , header = T , colClasses = c("year"="factor", "month"="factor"))
pie$month <- as.numeric(as.character(pie$month))
```
```{r include = FALSE}
# If I want to use for loop to print htmltools::tagList, this chunk is very important.
# However, I don't know why must need it.
plot_ly(QQ)
```
```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
for (i in unique(QQ$type)){
  cat("  \n#",  i, "  \n") 
  print(htmltools::tagList(plot_ly(summarise(group_by(QQ[QQ$type == i,], com, year),sum(value)), labels = ~com, values = ~`sum(value)`, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'inside',
        textinfo = 'label+percent',
        insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
        hoverinfo = 'text',
        text = ~paste(com, `sum(value)`),
        marker = list(colors = colors,
                      line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
        showlegend = T) %>%
  layout(title = '',
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)) 
  ))
  cat("  \n")
}
```
````

[image]

However, since my raw data has 2 years(2015 and 2016), I want to have 2 pie charts(2015 & 2016), maybe similar like this:

[image]

How can I use `for-loop` to output like this?

Moreover, I try `ifelse` but get error:

````
34 ```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, results='asis'}
35 for (i in unique(QQ$type)){
       cat("  \n#",  i, "  \n")
       if(QQ$type == i & QQ$year == "2015"){
       print(htmltools::tagList(plot_ly(filter(summarise(group_by(QQ[QQ$type == i,], com, year),sum(value)), year == "2015"), labels = ~com, values = ~`sum(value)`, type = 'pie',
          textposition = 'inside',
          textinfo = 'label+percent',
          insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
          hoverinfo = 'text',
          text = ~paste(com, `sum(value)`),
          marker = list(colors = colors,
                        line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
          showlegend = T) %>%
    layout(title = '',
           xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
           yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)) 
     ))
     } else {
      print(htmltools::tagList(plot_ly(filter(summarise(group_by(QQ[QQ$type == i,], com, year),sum(value)), year == "2016"), labels = ~com, values = ~`sum(value)`, type = 'pie',
           textposition = 'inside',
           textinfo = 'label+percent',
           insidetextfont = list(color = '#FFFFFF'),
           hoverinfo = 'text',
           text = ~paste(com, `sum(value)`),
           marker = list(colors = colors,
                         line = list(color = '#FFFFFF', width = 1)),
           showlegend = T) %>%
     layout(title = '',
            xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
            yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE)) 
      ))
    }
    cat("  \n")
  }}
  ```
````

[image]

very appreciate.